# How to set SSRS ConsumeContainerWhitespace property in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I am trying to set `ConsumeContainerWhitespace` using the Report Designer in Visual Studio 2008, but I can't find the property in the GUI. Since I can't find it, I'm wondering if this is new to VS 2010. Is it possible to set this property in VS 2008? If so, how is it done?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can set this property using the VS2008 GUI.  Just click on the report surface and hit F4 to bring up the properties window, and then select "Report" in the object selector at the top of the window.  You should then see the ConsumeContanierWhitespace property.  (see the screen shot below).

[image]

Comment: i still dont get it :(

Answer (score 1):

For those who have Visual Studio 2012

1. Click on the Report1.rdlc and it will open in the VS 2012
2. Click Outside the Report1.rdlc and PRESS F4 it will open Properties.
3. there you will find the ConsumeContainerWhiteSpace property.

Comment: Applicable for VS 2017