# How to add more data items than design view page height allows. I'm out of Design View vertical space

Tags: powerbi-paginated-reports

I understand that I can never exceed the width of a report body, but I have more report items than a (Design View) page can hold and I don't know what to do.

To clarify, what is currently on the Design View page correctly becomes a longer display view, and becomes multiple printed pages. Just what I want.

The problem is that I've run out of vertical design canvas and I don't know how to fix that.

Comment: What reporting tool are you using? PBI or SSRS/PBI-Paginated?

Comment: @billinkc, I'm using Paginated Report Builder - It's a sister product to Power BI Desktop. It is not Power BI Desktop though.

Answer (score 0):

Now that we've identified the PBI-Desktop tag was erroneous, the problem domain is SSRS Report Builder/PBI Paginated Report Builder doesn't give you enough space to craft your report.

The right but wrong answer is to go into the Property menu of the `Body` and there you can change the Size of the report.

[image]

Here you can see me manually increasing the size of the report body but it's easier/more precise to work with the property window.

[image]

Why it's the wrong answer -> You're designing a paginated report - one designed to be pica perfect on your page. Now we're stuffing a 21.875 inch body of a report into an 8x11 page piece of paper. Viewing of it might be ok but when someone clicks print, what happens? Is it going to squish all of that into a single page? Will Page 1 of the report really span N pages? It's been too long since I've worked with SSRS to that level of precision and I really don't remember but do test early if printing is a crucial aspect of the report delivery.

### Outdated PBI Desktop/Service answer in case someone else needs it

In Power BI Desktop, click in the background and under Visualizations go to the Format tab. Change the default page size to custom and I could create a 99999 pixel tall report but I doubt that's advisable

[image]

Comment: The addition of the Power BI tag may have been a dubious choice, but as you've shown there is some cross-knowledge between product users. Widening the canvas size *always* creates orphaned data and blank pages when printed. I suspect lengthening the canvas beyond the report body will do the same. I also suspect there is a tricky way to use sub-reports to get around this, but I have no guidance here.

Comment: Subreports can be difficult as when they have issues rendering, you have nothing but "Sorry, couldn't do it" and the error is swallowed somewhere along the way. For blank pages, you can try ConsumeContainerWhitespace https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9367229/how-to-set-ssrs-consumecontainerwhitespace-property-in-visual-studio-2008 and ... some other property that plays with it to instruct the engine to trim up the blank stuff